# Displaying page content using django-page-cms

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I would like to display some content located in my models in some of my template pages.

I am using django-page cms

In the documentation views are not used to display content. Instead ready made template tags are used.

http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/display-content.html

I do not understand a word of this. Please Bear with me I am new.

All I want to do is display some info located in my models inside a template this manner..

> ```
>    {% if latest_news_list %}          
>       {% for news in latest_news_list %} 
>            <li><h3>{{ news.title }}</h3></li>
>            <li><p>{{ news.body }}</p></li>
>       {% endfor %}
> ```

Since views are not used I cannot use if latest_news_list.
I need to somehow get my models to display in the templates using django-page cms and NOT regular views. The documentation states to use some kind of template tag for this.

Could somebody please explain to me how to do this.
And a clear concise explanation of the following ready-made template tags would also be appreciated...
    * get_content
    * show_content
    * get_page
    * show_absolute_url

taken from.http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/display-content.html

I need to display info contained using the following models in the manner I have highlighted above. Thank you very much for your help. my models are as follows.

```
class Body(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField("Main content")
```

As I have stated I am very new to this please make explanations as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template tags you mentioned are supposed to display content coming from the cms. If you want to include data coming from your app, you should see this section[link text](http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/display-content.html#id5).

```
def extra_context():
    from myapp.models import Body
    items = Body.object.all()
    return {'items': items}

PAGE_EXTRA_CONTEXT = extra_context


{% if items %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{ item.title }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    <ul>
{% endif %}
```

Or, if you want to use your app's view, see [this](http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/3rd-party-apps.html).