# How to display django model data on the django cms page template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I would like to be able to use my external app data on django cms page.
I am able to use custom plugin data but not data from normal django app

I tried creating views to handle my data but how do I call this view from django cms pages?
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854817/displaying-page-content-using-django-page-cms) is exactly what I am asking for but his explanation is shallow and the link provided in the answer is no longer in use.

Here is my model:

```
class ExternalArticle(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    source = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Please supply the source of the article",
        verbose_name="source of the article",
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        help_text="Please supply the title of the article",
        verbose_name="title of the article",
    )
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-original_publication_date"]

    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s:%s" % (self.source[0:60], self.title[0:60])
```

My template has placeholders

```
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">

             <div class="row">
                    <!-- header-->
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="updates">                           
                           {% placeholder "header" %}                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- header end-->

            </div> <!-- end row -->
```

but I don't mind displaying this data anywhere on the template if not possible inside a place holder
I have a custom page that I am using in Django cms.
I would like to display the above data is a section in the Django cms page
If this model was inheriting from `CMSPlugin` then that would be easy because I could use a custom plugin in my placeholder

I expect to display the data from my model in the template.

Comment: Have you created a plugin or apphook or context processor to make your model available to the CMS?

Comment: I thought it was possible to achieve this without a plugin, but if it is not possible without then I will create a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ArticlesPluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ArticlesPluginModel
    name = _("Articles")
    render_template = "article_plugin/articles.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ArticlesPluginPublisher, self).render(
            context, instance, placeholder
        )
        context.update(
            {
                "articles": Article.objects.order_by(
                    "-original_publication_date"
                )
            }
        )
        return context
```

The plugin model(`ArticlesPluginModel`) is just for storing the configurations for the instance of the plugin. Not the actual articles.
Then the render will just add to the context the relevant articles from the external app(`Article`)

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow connect the `ExternalArticle` with a page object. For example

- by defining the `ExternalArticle` as a [page extension](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html)
- or with an [`AppHook`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/apphooks.html)
- or - low-tech - with a [`PageField`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/fields.html#model-fields) on the `ExternalArticle` model

Answer (score -1):

```
  {% load cms_tags %}
<h1>{{ instance.poll.question }}</h1>

<form action="{% url polls.views.vote poll.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} 
        {% for choice in instance.poll.choice_set.all %}
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
          <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br /> 
         {% endfor %} 

          <input type="submit" value="Vote" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: I already tried this one out but it cannot work on Django cms templates. It works well for normal Django templates

Comment: make sure you added this {% load cms_tags %}

Comment: I just edited my question with a snippet of my template. So I would like to show the data anywhere inside the class `updates` whether using the placeholder is possible or not

Comment: see if you want to display data in template you need to pass context in view please add view snippet

Comment: the way cms works is different from the way django views work. I hope your answers are in reference to django cms and not just django, because all that you say makes sense in normal django app whereby we use views to connect model and templates

Comment: I thought it was possible to achieve this without a plugin, but if it is not possible then I will create a plugin.

Comment: @joseluke but a plugin might not be the proper function for this. The model looks like it'd form part of a new application, so that'd be an apphook that you'd be looking at. It completely depends on the scope of this model & what's right for your project.

Comment: I think the plugin will work because I might want to have different configurations for different pages.